# ¿Como visualizar el log de errores en Visual Studio - Android?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, log

Estoy probando una app `Xamarin.Android` que funciona sin problemas en `Android 10` e inferiores; pero al intentar correr la app utilizando un dispositivo con `Android 11` me crashea inmediatamente.

No me muestra ningún error simplemente se cierra de golpe y no inicia.

He escuchado que hay un Log donde podemos tratar de descifrar los errores pero no se como activar/abrir el `Log de errores`.

Intente seleccionar en la ventana `Salida` la opción `Xamarin Diagnostics`, pero no estoy seguro si es ese el log de errores.

[image: Salida]

Comment: Esta es la documentación oficial: [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows)